# math.js acting unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, precision, math.js

> Chrome 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)
>
> math.js v3.10.0

Using the code below I get `false`. Am I not doing this right?

```
math.config({'number': 'BigNumber'});
console.log(math.largerEq('120', '2'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z2jmLndn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You're passing in the values as strings, pass them as number values:</strike>

```
math.config({'number': 'BigNumber'});
console.log(math.largerEq(120, 2));
```

OP Found answer:

```
console.log(math.largerEq(math.bignumber('120'), math.bignumber('2')));
```

It appears that the math.config() isn't properly working as far as accepting the values as BigNumber, insight would be appreciated.

Comment: http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/largerEq.html says that strings are fine. My example is heavily simplified and I have chosen to use this library because I need accurate math calculations. JS's "fun-ness" with `alert(.1+.2);` does not fly well for me. I could easily be passing in more than 16 decimal places into the `largerEq()` function.

Comment: Perhaps they imply that by accepting strings, math.js will perform typical string comparison instead. `math.largerEq('120', '002')` gives the result you want.

Comment: Looks like you are right though. Anyways, you've led me to try `console.log(math.largerEq(math.bignumber('120'), math.bignumber('2')));` instead. I was simply under the impression that my `config()` call would make the library assume this. I am definitely not farcing around with the idea of padding strings with zeros. If I would so good at this then I wouldn't need a library.

Comment: It seems like the config just isn't sticking, maybe it's a different syntax?

Comment: Not sure. Using `math.eval()` brings me out to 64 decimal places appropriately with that `config()` call; without it then it uses native JS arithmetic.

Comment: Anyways, if you'd like to add the code which you've led me to try then I'd be happy to accept your answer.